# Partition of Naturals in Arithmetic Progression

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis

In Stein and Shakarchi's *Complex Analysis*, Problem 22 of Chapter 1 reads

> **Problem.** Let $\mathbf N=\{1, 2, 3, \ldots \}$.
>   A subset $S$ of $\mathbf N$ is said to be in arithmetic progression is there exists $a$ and $d$ in $\mathbf N$ such that $S=\{a, a+d, a+2d, \ldots\}$.
>   The number $d$ is called the *step size* of $S$.
>   Show that $\mathbf N$ cannot be partitioned into arithmetic progressions with pairwise distinct step sizes (except for the trivial case when there is only one AP).

First I would like to say that it is quite frustrating to not be able to solve this problem by an elementary combinatorial kind of argument.
I tried for a long time and made a little bit of progress but am nowhere close to a solution. If you have an elementary proof then please share it.

After some time I read the hint, which essentially asked to consider the power series $\sum_{n\in \mathbf N} z^n$.

Following the hint, suppose $A_1, \ldots, A_n$ be APs with pairwise distinct step sizes which partition $\mathbf N$.
Say $A_i=\{a_i, a_i+d_i, a_i+2d_i, \ldots\}$.
Then we have
$$\frac{z}{1-z}  = \frac{z^{a_1}}{1-z^{d_1}}+\cdots + \frac{z^{a_n}}{1-z^{d_n}}$$

in the interior of the closed unit disc.

But even from here I am not able to finish the argument.

Comment: Judging by the answers at [this MathOverflow question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/25313/finitely-many-arithmetic-progressions), there may well not be an elementary combinatorial argument.